# Bootstrap 3 $('#myTab a[href=" about_us.html #directors"]').tab('show')

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, jquery-plugins

In Bootstrap 3 I want href location to next page.

example home page has aboutus.html and in aboutus page I have a section called #directors.

I tried this method but not able find the solution 
from home page to about us page data-target

```
[<a data-target="$('#myTab a[href="about_us.html#directors"]')"
    data-toggle="tab" href=" about_us.html#directors">Directors</a>]
```

Comment: put some relevant code

Comment: Not sure what you want, or what doesn't work. But I can see you have "aboutus" in your prose and `about_us` in the code. You may want to look into that.

Comment: @DrixsonOseña There was code. Not very visible though.